# python: replacing ints for strings from the binary vectors

Tags: python, string, list, replace

So my problem is that I cannot replace any value from a list of binary vectors to a string. My list looks like:

```
[[0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

I want to replace the ones from these vectors but according to indexes of those ones.
I tried something like this:

```
for row in list:
    if(row[0] == 1):
        row[0] == 'Alarm0'
    else:
        row[0] == ' '
    if(row[1] == 1):
        row[1] == 'Alarm1'
    else:
        row[1] == ' '
```

And same way for each row from the list. I know that it isn't efficient way to do this and however it even doesn't work. It gives me error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

So I would like to remove all 0 values and replace strings where there is 1, but the appriopate new text depends on index, where '1' appears.
My output should be:

```
[[Alarm3, Alarm6, Alarm11] -> because I have ones on indexes 3,6,11 in my input list
 [Alarm6, Alarm8, Alarm10]
           .
           . same concept for all rows
           .
 [Alarm14]]
```

I will be grateful for any advices.

EDIT:
Each Alarm should be an unique string, Alarms with indexes are only my examples. In real, I have alarms like "CONNECTIONS LOST". Alarm0,Alarm1,Alarm2 are only here to boost description of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate over every `row` with a **`for` loop**. You can then use another *nested* `for` loop that iterates over the row. Every time it finds a one, it should add the corresponding alarm to another list. At the end of the nested `for` loop, we replace the old list with the constructed, like:

```
for ri,row in enumerate(data):
    under_construction = []
    for idx,elm in enumerate(row):
        if elm:
            under_construction.append('Alarm{0}'.format(idx))
    data[ri] = under_construction
```

The above is not very elegant: we can use *list comprehension* to construct a new list, and use *slice assignment* to elegantly replace the entire row:

```
for row in data:
    row[:] = ['Alarm{0}'.format(idx) for idx,elm in enumerate(row) if elm]
```

If you do not want to update `data` inplace, but want to construct a new 2d-list, we can turn it into *nested list comprehension*:

```
result = [['Alarm{0}'.format(idx) for idx,elm in enumerate(row) if elm] for row in data]
```

For example (based on your sample data):

```
>>> data = [[0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
... [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0],
... [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
... [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
... [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],
... [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]]
>>> 
>>> [['Alarm{0}'.format(idx) for idx,elm in enumerate(row) if elm] for row in data]
[['Alarm3', 'Alarm6', 'Alarm11'], ['Alarm6', 'Alarm8', 'Alarm10'], ['Alarm1', 'Alarm4'], ['Alarm8'], ['Alarm8', 'Alarm12'], ['Alarm14']]
```

**EDIT**

In case the alarm have a different name, we can use a *list of alarm names*: e.g.:

```
alarm_names = ['CONNECTION LOST', 'INTRUDER ALARM', 'Alarm 2', 'Alarm3', ...]
```

Then we can rewrite the in-place code to `zip`:

```
for row in data:
    row[:] = [name for elm,name in zip(row,alarm_names) if elm]
```

Or for generating a new list:

```
result = [[name for elm,name in zip(row,alarm_names) if elm] for row in data]
```

with `alarm_names`:

```
>>> alarm_names
['CONNECTION LOST', 'INTRUDER ALARM', 'Alarm 2', 'Alarm 3', 'Alarm 4', 'Alarm 5', 'Alarm 6', 'Alarm 7', 'Alarm 8', 'Alarm 9', 'Alarm 10', 'Alarm 11', 'Alarm 12', 'Alarm 13', 'Alarm 14', 'Alarm 15', 'Alarm 16', 'Alarm 17', 'Alarm 18', 'Alarm 19', 'Alarm 20', 'Alarm 21', 'Alarm 22', 'Alarm 23', 'Alarm 24', 'Alarm 25', 'Alarm 26', 'Alarm 27', 'Alarm 28', 'Alarm 29', 'Alarm 30', 'Alarm 31', 'Alarm 32', 'Alarm 33', 'Alarm 34', 'Alarm 35', 'Alarm 36']
```

we get:

```
>>> [[name for elm,name in zip(row,alarm_names) if elm] for row in data]
[['Alarm 3', 'Alarm 6', 'Alarm 11'], ['Alarm 6', 'Alarm 8', 'Alarm 10'], ['INTRUDER ALARM', 'Alarm 4'], ['Alarm 8'], ['Alarm 8', 'Alarm 12'], ['Alarm 14']]
```

notice the `'INTRUDER ALARM'`.

Comment: Pretty cool. But it is only my example, my real strings aren't "Alarm0,Alarm1,Alarm2..." but each has special, unique text like "CONNECTION LOST", "INTRUDER ALARM". Sorry for causing this problem.